# Do you really need to use the specified voltage to drive a transistor?

Tags: voltage, transistors

I just bought a pack of 2222A NPN transistors from a local electronics shop.

I found some datasheets online (e.g. https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf ) that say the emitter-base voltage is 6v.

Does that mean that I cannot use this transistor with a 3v or 5v power supply?

(In the past I never looked at the specs and just wired the transistor with a resistor at the base, and it all worked.  I am trying to reconcile my cowboy experience with a new practice of reading datasheets, and I am getting confused.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The emitter-base voltage of 6V is the Maximum rating. Go beyond that and it will destroy the device. It is NOT the normal operating voltage. That entire section is the ratings to avoid destruction.

Also, although the data-sheet is vague on the point, the emitter-base voltage of 6V is the maximum reverse voltage (ie with the base negative with respect to the emitter).

The "Maximum" or "Absolute Maximum" section is often close to the beginning of a datasheet.

The characteristics or normal operating conditions part of the datasheet is the place you will find the data on how to use the device normally.

Biasing the base with a resistor is a perfectly reasonable way to use the transistor and 3-5V for the collector supply is also perfectly reasonable.

A transistor can operate over a wide range of voltages and currents so even if your design doesn't match the conditions shown in the datasheet it may still be legitimate (providing you don't exceed the limits indicated in the absolute maximum section).

Comment: The specification in question was Veb which is the reverse emitter to base voltage.

Comment: OKay, thank you very much, that is helpful.

Comment: The datasheet is not vague on the point--it specifically says 6 V is the maximum emitter-base voltage, not the maximum base-emitter voltage (which would be in the vicinity of 0.6-0.7 volts, as it's a diode). The first node mentioned is to be considered positive with respect to the second node (or, if the voltage named is negative, negative).

Comment: @Hearth - I consider that vague. This rule is violated in this data sheet for a PNP transistor for example: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n3906-d.pdf

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, there are surprisingly many parts that can be used "off-datasheet". A classic example is using a backwards transistor, and a capacitor, to make an oscillator. Another one is using a CMOS NOT gate with negative feedback to make an amplifier.

Comment: Half a century ago, when Zeners were a bit expensive, it was common to use a reverse-biased emitter-base junction as a cheap ~7V Zener. Big fat gold-doped transistors like 2N2222A did not suffer damage if the current was moderate. Don't do this with more modern types, though.

Comment: @KevinWhite: Many parts have parasitic resistance, conductance, capacitance, and inductance, which may make the part less susceptible to damage from some forms of potential overstress, but more susceptible to others.  If one were to drive a bunch of logic chips of a the same typical type from a positive supply rail, and connected the inputs of some to a 5.25 volt supply with no current limit, and the inputs of others to a 1 microamp supply with no upper voltage limit, some chips in the first batch might have currents that exceed 1 microamp, and some in the second might have voltages that...

Comment: @JohnDoty - I've also used the base-emitter breakdown of transistors as a zener diode. I didn't realize that the gold-doping would affect its robustness though.

Comment: @supercat - I'm not sure what point you are making. For TTL devices that did have lower max voltage on their inputs than the main supply they also had a significant leakage current into the input due to the reverse Hfe that was separate from any breakdown. The data sheet limit was 400uA for standard TTL so 1uA leakage wouldn't have been detectable.

Comment: @KevinWhite: My point is that in many cases, parts will be designed with an uncertain clamp voltage/current curve, but designed so that they will safely endure any situation where voltage is within a certain range *or* where the magnitude of the current is below a certain level.  If a part has a maximum input voltage of VDD+300mV, the part might have clamp diodes that can't dissipate any power but wouldn't conduct any current at that voltage, or it might have clamp diodes that would conduct 100mA but can safely dissipate 30mW.  Other circuitry shouldn't rely upon the part...

Comment: ...clamping the pin to VDD+300mV, nor upon its refraining from conducting substantial clamp currents at a lower voltage, but merely on its refraining from conducting enough clamp current to damage itself unless the voltage exceeds VDD+300mV.

Comment: @supercat - agreed. It can be specially insidious for voltages outside the supply rails as it can cause substrate injection with resultant weird effects. Unfortunately many data sheets do not specify limits for many of these effects. I still don't see how this would apply to an individual discrete transistor that was the subject of the question.

Comment: @KevinWhite: A back-biased transistor junction at any voltage V below the data sheet maximum might reasonably conduct anywhere between zero current and the device's maximum power dissipation divided by V.